# Is there is a way to tell Solr to store the entire index as one file, instead of segments

Tags: solr, full-text-search, search-engine, lucene

I would like to Solr to store entire index instead of multiple segments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest thing would be to optimize it, documented here:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrOperationsTools#optimize

Generally speaking, a Lucene optimize reduces the index to a single segment.  Certain variables can change that behavior, such that an optimize may not reduce to a single segment.

Note that this is a very expensive operation, and should generally not be done very frequently.  Documents added, modified, or deleted will cause new segments to be created and require you to reoptimize.